# ZF1 parent route not found in chained routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm writting an application in Zend Framework 1.12. And there is a problem with routing. I use routing form xml.
Here is part of file:

```
<panel route="/panel">
    <defaults controller="index" action="index" module="panel"/>
    <chains>
        <summary route="/summary">
            <defaults controller="index" action="index" module="panel"/>
        </summary>
        <user route="/user">
            <defaults controller="user" action="index" module="panel"/>
            <chains>
                <info route="/info">
                    <defaults controller="user" action="index" module="panel"/>
                </info>
                <edit route="/edit">
                    <defaults controller="user" action="edit" module="panel"/>
                </edit>
                <change-password route="/password">
                    <defaults controller="user" action="change-password" module="panel"/>
                </change-password>
            </chains>
        </user>
    </chains>
</panel>
```

Now the problem:
If i declare routes like this the route panel is not seen(No route matched the request). Of course I can split the chains and declare each route separately but I think it is not good idea.
I found a way to address "/panel" will by accessible by adding empty static route to chains(called for example index) bu it will make ony addres accessible no route. Litle explain: By adding this i will have route "panel.index" and the rest but still trying to find route "panel" will end with Exception.

And now the question: Is there a way to make route "panel" visible?